# Coding a relative path to file in OS X

Tags: macos, haskell

In a Haskell project I'm working on I normally use a windows environment. For debugging purposes I'm loading up a file located in the same folder as my source code.

In windows, this works:

```
main = do
    foo <- ByteString.readFile "fileName.foo";
    -- whatever
```

However when I build this project in OS X and run it, I get a file not found error. How exactly do I specify the path to a file that is located in the executable's folder?

Comment: I don't have access to a computer with OS X, but on both windows and linux `"fileName"` and `"./fileName"` work, it is probably the case that OS X is starting your executable in a different directory than you think. If you are just trying to do this "for debugging" then it is probably best to abandon it, as such platform-independence is just going to be a big headache... if you actually needed to do this portably, you should use cabals `data-dir` section, instead of relying on things like "the current directory".

Comment: @user2407038 I normally execute a scrip file located in the source directoy that deletes *.o files and such and launches the executable. Even if I manually run the executable by double clicking on it,I get the same error. I know very little about OS X but I can't quite figure out how the executable can be starting in a different directory in such circumstances. You are right thought about making this platform independent and will look into `System.Directory`